# Change columns string value inside a stored procedure based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, and was wondering if it is possible to create a condition inside a stored procedure that will check for a string value, and replace it.

For example something like:

```
if [column name] = 'Adam'
then [column name] = 'BoB'
```

Also if this condition could be inside another select Case

eq:

```
SELECT
    a.projectName,
    a.user
    CASE
       WHEN a.TYPEID = 2 
          THEN 
              -- condition / change name
              CONCAT(a.[MESSAGE], a.Name) 
FROM 
    some_table a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` constructs can be nested, see here:

```
SELECT
    a.projectName,
    a.user,
    Case when a.TYPEID = 2 THEN
      concat(a.[MESSAGE] ,
       Case a.Name when 'Adam' Then 'Bob' else a.Name end)
    End msg
From some_table a
```

This is assuming that you want to concat the optionally changed name to the MESSAGE. Concatenation can also be done by using the `+` operator in sql-server.

It is not quite clear from your question what you want to happen, if `TYPEID != 2`. Currently nothing (`null`) gets output.

Comment: TYPEID != 2 was not needed here.

The nesting here will do the trick i think, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace([column name], 'Adam', 'Bob') would work.  However this would also change 'Adams' to 'Bobs'.  You need to do more work if you want to work more specifically.